# How to Open Files on Xamarin Android Using FilePicker

Tags: xamarin.android

I asked a similar question several days ago but couldn't reply or use until now (due to work issues). Anyway, here's the code I have:

```
    using Xamarin.Essentials; (at the top of the file)
    async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
    {
        
        try
        {
            var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
            if (result != null)
            {
                string Text = $"File Name: {result.FileName}";
                if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                    Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // The user canceled or something went wrong
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
   The name FilePicker does not exist in the current context.
```

There are several other similar errors.

Any help is very appreciated.

RON

Comment: The FilePicker is the api of the Xamarin.Essentials, so this error shouldn't appear if you add  `using Xamarin.Essentials;` in the right place.

Comment: I agree. Mystified. The using statement is at the beginning of the file, with the rest of them.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Yes. Deleted the using statement for Essentials, etc. Deleted the bin and obj folders. Unloaded VS. Restarted VS, added the using statement for essentials. Cleaned; rebuilt all. Same result.

Comment: Yes. Clean and rebuilt. I've deployed the app for about a year+, no problems. Now. one problem after another. (see my next problem)

Comment: You can try to use Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker instead of use using Xamarin.Essentials.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem and I solved it using Xamarin.essentials 1.7 (until here) , but not work in 1.6 less or 1.7 >

Comment: Thanks!!! It's been a long while since I downloaded via nuget.

Comment: I did install 1.8. But I still have the same problem. (See my new problem post)

Comment: Can you create a clear proyect? , and try it , the first that you install is xamarin.essentials, I use xamarin.essentials for geoloc the version 1.6,and this is working well

Comment: It's now working ok, to an extent. I can click on a button to open and look at files in the Documents (or other) folders and I can open them.